# Where should I ask journalism/media studies questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I enrolled in the media studies master program at the university and as long term SE user, and I find it quite surprising that there is no SE site for this field.

**Is there a proper place to ask these questions?**

Questions I am now inventing out of scratch, just to hint the idea:

- *Is there a precedent of shutting off presidential speech on TV?*
- *What is the impact of the BBC in the world?*
- *How many people consume news on a daily basis in developing countries?*
- *What was the historically first newspapers with online-only access?*

Comment: Do you have examples of things you already know you want to ask about? Questions you've thought of asking? If there's no site for the entire field, you'll probably be dependent on your questions overlapping with other fields, and having examples could help figure out which fields :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I tried to invent some example questions.

Comment: The second sample question is broad/opinion based and is unlikely to work on any site here. The first and last are really history questions rather than being about journalism.

Comment: @RobertLongson One of the media studies branches is studying the history of the media, correct.  About the second one: I expect it would be described properly in the description, with a precise definition of impact (these are only headers), but it is definitely measurable.

Comment: For your third question if you asked "What datasets are there of news consumption in low and middle income countries?" then that might fit on the OpenData stack. You might have to define what you mean by news in the question. Obviously you would have to analyse the data yourself.

Comment: Some of these might fit on [history.se] or maybe [politics.se]. (I don't know either of those sites well, so don't take my word for it, but check out their scope and search for similar questions.)